# Cannot find symbol in main method

Tags: java

Made a Tester class to test how a method passes arguments into a parameter.

Below is the code that I have written up.

```
public class Testcalculate {

public static void main (String [] args){

 Testcalculate c = new Testcalculate();
 c.add(40, 50);

} // end main

} // end class

class calculate {

 public void add(int x, int y) {

 int a = x + y;

 System.out.print("Total is: " + a);

}

}
```

The error message that I get says:

```
Testcalculate.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol : method add(int, int)
location: class Testcalculate
c.add(40,50);
```

I have passed arguments into the method, using the correct values of type int.
I just don't understand what is causing this issue. I've even tried putting the public keyword before the add method declaration in the second class, thinking it may be out of scope, but that doesn't help.

Both classes are placed within the same text file.

Answer (score 6):

There's no `Testcalculate#add` method. In other words the class `Testcalculate` doesn't have a `calculate` method, thus you receive the compiler error. Probably you meant:

```
calculate c = new calculate();
c.add(40, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to do this:

```
public class Testcalculate {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        Testcalculate c = new Testcalculate();
        c.add(40, 50);

    } // end main

    public void add(int x, int y) {

        int a = x + y;

        System.out.print("Total is: " + a);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either move add into Testcalculate

```
public class Testcalculate {

public static void main (String [] args){

 Testcalculate c = new Testcalculate();
 c.add(40, 50);

} // end main


 public void add(int x, int y) {

 int a = x + y;

 System.out.print("Total is: " + a);

}

} // end class
```

or change main to

```
public static void main (String [] args){

 calculate c = new calculate();
 c.add(40, 50);

} // end main
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your `add` method on your `calculate` class, but you're trying to invoke it on an instance of `Testcalculate`. To fix it, you should make `c` be an instance of `calculate`:

```
 calculate c = new calculate();
 c.add(40, 50);
```

In addition, you should follow Java naming conventions, and name this class `Calculate` (with an uppercase 'C') rather than `calculate`.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing explanation. Won't repeat this embarrasing mistake in the near future!